# Add another regular expression to an existing expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm not familair with regular expressions. I'm trying to understand it, but it's difficult.

I've got a regular expression which will wrap any URL in an anchor tag. However, it's also wrapping URLs which are already in an anchor tag. I would like to prevent that, so I found a regular expression which does this for me.

```
?![^<]*</a>
```

However, I have no idea how I would add this to my existing regular expression. This is my current regular expression:

```
preg_replace('!(((ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text); ?>
```

So, how can I skip an URL that is already wrapped in an anchor tag?

Comment: Please clear your question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna join the choir and say: **Don't use regex for this - use a html parser**.

This said - the regex you *found* isn't really a regex in itself. It's part of a negative look-ahead that *kind of* checks you aren't in an anchor. (It should really be `(?![^<]*</a>)`.) It checks that following text up to the next `<` (or the end) isn't followed by `</>`.

Appending this to the en of your original RE will **sometimes** do the trick. I won't spend time thinking of situations it'll fail - but it probably will.

Along with some simplifications your regex should look like this:

```
(https?:\/\/[-\wа-яА-Я()@:%+.~#?&;\/=]+)(?![^<]*<\/a>)
```

This probably will work for you *mostly*, but probably will fail at times as well.

Regards

Comment: Alright, thanks. I will go for a HTML parser instead.